# SSDT db-project compare throws "source schema drift detected" for members of sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, visual-studio-2019

We are using SSDT database projects where changes will be done in the dev-DB, then a compare is done between the devDB and the VS-DBproject and selected changes is updated into the VS-project. Lately (maybe for about a month) the update of the VS-project has started to fail for me with the message "Source schema drift detected. Press Compare to refresh the comparison". There is no changes going on in the database at the time, of that I am sure (tried against several databases, also very small ones that no one else is using).

There are a couple of strange things that I cannot explain:

- We have three environments, dev, test and prod. The problem only happens when going against the dev or test-environments. Against prod it works. All three servers have the same version of SQL Server and Windows Server.
- We are several developers, but the problem only occur for some. After further investigation, it seems that those who get the problem are those that have sysadmin permissions on the SQL Server.

There is a workaround that is working for me: I can create a DacPac of the source DB and do the compare against that, and then the update will go fine. But this is more cumbersome to do. It is OK as long as it is only the sysadmins with the problem, but if all developers should get this problem...the workaround would be a problem.

Any one else have seen this problem? Any suggestions?

Our environment:
All developers use software installed on a Windows Server 2019:
Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.11.16
SSDT 16.0.62205.05200

SQL Server is running on a Windows Server 2016.
SQL SErver version is: 15.0.4312.2